# Getting 64-bit data in WM_COPYDATA command instead of expected 32-bit DWORD

Tags: windows-7, types, 64-bit

I have an old Windows app, compiled in Visual C++ 6.0, that I need to get working on x64 platforms. The app actually seems to be ok since I used a pretty careful data typing but it interacts with an Outlook add-in that I've had to recompile as an x64 dll just to get it to load into Outlook 64-bit edition.

The add-in sends data to the main application using a WM_COPYDATA message, the data sent is a struct as follows:

```
{
DWORD dwData1;
char pszData2[32];
DWORD dwData3;
}
```

Things aren't working so I did some debugging, and it turns out that when the 64-bit add-in sends data to the 32-bit program, the DWORDs are coming in as 64 bits (8 bytes) each, throwing the struct off completely since the program expects 32 bit DWORDs (4 bytes). Looking at the data in memory, I can see the extra 4 bytes for each of the DWORDS, before and after the 32-byte string.

Now doing some research here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. I see that DWORD supposedly has retained 32-bit length even on x64 platforms as a choice by Microsoft. And doing a TRACE(sizeof(DWORD)) in 64-bit land I get 4 bytes as expected.

So what could be causing my 64-bit add-in to send 64 bits with each DWORD?

I worked around this by changing my struct definition to use DWORD32 but I'd like to "get" the fundamental concept in order to know where else this might be affecting my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like the packing changed.

Use [`#pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) around your structure declaration to prevent the compiler from inserting padding.

Comment: Aha! Should have known. Putting #pragma pack(4) before the struct seems to have done the trick! Thanks, Ben. Someone please vote this up!

Comment: @Nicholas: Although you don't yet have the ability to cast upvotes, you should be able to approve an answer to your question, by clicking the checkmark outline that appears to the left of my answer.

Comment: @Nicholas: Also, I recommend using push and pop so you don't affect the packing for the rest of the program.

Comment: This link was helpful to me. For VS2008 I did not need pack for 32/64 bit IPC.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppSendWMCOPYDATA-f75bc681/